# A simple distructor program gives me different output in debugging then running it?

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        class A
        {
            int x, y;
            public A(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
            public int add() { return x + y; }
            public int sub() { return x - y; }
            ~A()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Detroyed");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A ob = new A(9, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(ob.add());
            Console.WriteLine(ob.sub());
            ob = null;
            System.GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("End");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The output in running

```
11
5
End
Destroyed
```

But in Debugging mode it gives this output

```
11
5
Destroyed
End
```

Comment: You might want to add `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` after your `GC.Collect` call. But fundamentally the GC is more conservative when running in a debugger. When not in a debugger, you shouldn't even need the `ob = null` to observe the object being finalized.

Comment: just i added a break point and press F11 see the output

Comment: But My sir teach me and in his pc(VS 2012). The output is this

Comment: I just want to say this i am calling destructor first then "Destroyed" must be print first then "End". but in running mode(F5) "End" is printing first then "Destroyed"

Comment: You're not calling the finalizer at all. The GC is, whenever it wants to, in a separate thread. You don't have control over this. There's no "must" about it.

Comment: if there is something you need done at a specific point you might want to implement the `IDisposable` interface and use `using` statements to make sure the `Dispose` method is called when you want, if what you want is to release un-managed resources.  For anything else just add a method and call it when needed.

Comment: I'm concerned that it thinks 9+4=11.